# Artificial Intelligence Project - Thermostat AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I need very basic help (hopefully) on an Artificial Intelligence Project. My question is very basic so I won't be getting into many details other than what is required. My question starts with a description of the problem, which is to determine the best route to change the temperature. This sounds very vague but to clear things up it is for developing a thermostat. I want to be able to properly control temperature in the most efficient way by using a variety of sensors including outside temperature, humidity, motion in the home (whether someone is home or not), etc.

An example might help as well: Lets say its summer time and the A/C is on. The setpoint is set to 77, but the temperature is 79. However, nobody is home. But the thermostat knows the user will be back home at exactly 4pm in which it is currently 1 pm. And according to weather websites, the outside temperature is going to drop to 77 at 3 pm. The humidity is very high which also plays a big factor. Should the A/C turn on? If so for how long?

My real question is what AI Technique should I look into to solve this kind of problem. I want to simulate something similar situations in python before deploying it on an Android/Java level. I am a very beginner in the area of Artificial Intelligence and want to know the quickest and best manner to approach this problem while making sure I understand everything there is to know about AI at this project level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a neural network to predict the status of the thermostat and control it behavior which is based on several parameters. Thermal neural networks may help.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not expert, but for this kind of issues prefer using Fuzzy Logic or Expert Systems.